# `getaddrinfo`: what specifies its data source in the POSIX standard?

Tags: dns, posix

I wanted to check [`getaddrinfo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getaddrinfo.html) is expected to use Unbound when it's installed. Unless I overlooked something in this specification, it does not refer to any data sources it is required to check: ex. no references to `/etc/hosts` nor to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

What in the POSIX standards, specifies the data source `getaddrinfo` and `getnameinfo` are required to use? Or is this left to the OS free will?

Comment: That's out of the scope of the POSIX specification. POSIX just specifies an API.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain it's upto the OS. It's what [NSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch) typically handles.

Comment: So after your words, that's left to the OS free wills. So feel free to add this as an answer if it is so. Does POSIX back this up? Not that I don't trust you (I suspected the same after the lack of this precision in the page), just that I would welcome a reference. @muru, thanks for the reference to NSS, which I did not knew so far.

Comment: POSIX,1 is silent on this issue.  It is an implementation issue.